# ClassCastException when loading oauth2 access token from JdbcObjectStore

Tags: oauth, mule

In Mule EE 3.8.5 I am getting a ClassCastException when loading an oauth2 access token. I'm using mule-module-security-oauth2-provider version 1.7.2 and mule-module-objectstore 2.1.0

The stracktrace starts:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.AccessTokenStoreHolder
at org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.ObjectStoreTokenStore.retrieveByAccessToken(ObjectStoreTokenStore.java:38)
at org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.TokenManager.getNonExpiredAccessTokenHolder(TokenManager.java:116)
at org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.OAuth2ProviderModule.validate(OAuth2ProviderModule.java:543)
at org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.processors.ValidateMessageProcessor$1.process(ValidateMessageProcessor.java:178)
at org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.adapters.OAuth2ProviderModuleProcessAdapter$1.execute(OAuth2ProviderModuleProcessAdapter.java:36)
at org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.processors.ValidateMessageProcessor.doProcess(ValidateMessageProcessor.java:164)
```

My config has the token stored successfully into a simple H2 database table of the form:

create table ACCESSTOKENOBJECTSTORE (k varchar(1000), v varchar(1000000))

I can see the tokens being created in this table, but I get the ClassCastException when trying to validate the token. My flow looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2/current/mule-oauth2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider/current/mule-oauth2-provider.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/api-platform-gw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/api-platform-gw/current/mule-api-platform-gw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cors http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cors/current/mule-cors.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd">

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
        name="dataSource">
        <spring:property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/h2/h2db" />
        <spring:property name="username" value="sa" />
        <spring:property name="password" value="sa" />
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean name="accessTokenJdbcStore"
        class="org.mule.transport.jdbc.store.JdbcObjectStore">
        <spring:property name="jdbcConnector" ref="accessTokenJdbcConnector"></spring:property>
        <spring:property name="insertQueryKey" value="insertQueryKey"></spring:property>
        <spring:property name="selectQueryKey" value="selectQueryKey"></spring:property>
        <spring:property name="deleteQueryKey" value="deleteQueryKey"></spring:property>
        <spring:property name="clearQueryKey" value="clearQueryKey"></spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean name="refreshTokenJdbcStore"
        class="org.mule.transport.jdbc.store.JdbcObjectStore">
        <spring:property name="jdbcConnector" ref="refreshTokenJdbcConnector"></spring:property>
        <spring:property name="insertQueryKey" value="insertQueryKey"></spring:property>
        <spring:property name="selectQueryKey" value="selectQueryKey"></spring:property>
        <spring:property name="deleteQueryKey" value="deleteQueryKey"></spring:property>
        <spring:property name="clearQueryKey" value="clearQueryKey"></spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean name="tokenStore"
        class="org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.ObjectStoreTokenStore">
        <spring:property name="refreshTokenObjectStore" ref="refreshTokenJdbcStore" />
        <spring:property name="accessTokenObjectStore" ref="accessTokenJdbcStore" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<jdbc-ee:connector name="refreshTokenJdbcConnector"
    pollingFrequency="1000" dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    transactionPerMessage="false" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc-ee:query key="insertQueryKey"
        value="insert into REFRESHTOKENOBJECTSTORE (k,v) values (?,?)"></jdbc-ee:query>
    <jdbc-ee:query key="selectQueryKey"
        value="select k,v from REFRESHTOKENOBJECTSTORE where k = ?"></jdbc-ee:query>
    <jdbc-ee:query key="deleteQueryKey"
        value="delete from REFRESHTOKENOBJECTSTORE where k = ?"></jdbc-ee:query>
    <jdbc-ee:query key="clearQueryKey" value="delete from REFRESHTOKENOBJECTSTORE"></jdbc-ee:query>
</jdbc-ee:connector>

<jdbc-ee:connector name="accessTokenJdbcConnector"
    pollingFrequency="1000" dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    transactionPerMessage="false" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc-ee:query key="insertQueryKey"
        value="insert into ACCESSTOKENOBJECTSTORE (k,v) values (?,?)"></jdbc-ee:query>
    <jdbc-ee:query key="selectQueryKey"
        value="select k,v from ACCESSTOKENOBJECTSTORE where k = ?"></jdbc-ee:query>
    <jdbc-ee:query key="deleteQueryKey"
        value="delete from ACCESSTOKENOBJECTSTORE where k = ?"></jdbc-ee:query>
    <jdbc-ee:query key="clearQueryKey" value="delete from ACCESSTOKENOBJECTSTORE"></jdbc-ee:query>
</jdbc-ee:connector>


<objectstore:config name="accessTokenObjectStore"
    objectStore-ref="accessTokenJdbcStore"></objectstore:config>
<objectstore:config name="refreshTokenObjectStore"
    objectStore-ref="refreshTokenJdbcStore"></objectstore:config>

<oauth2-provider:config name="OAuth_provider_module"
    accessTokenEndpointPath="oauth/token" providerName="CustomProvider"
    authorizationEndpointPath="oauth/authorize" listenerConfig-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
    supportedGrantTypes="CLIENT_CREDENTIALS" doc:name="OAuth provider module"
    scopes="SOMETHING" enableRefreshToken="true" tokenStore-ref="tokenStore">
    <oauth2-provider:clients>
        <oauth2-provider:client clientId="abc" secret="def"
            type="CONFIDENTIAL">
            <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
                <oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>CLIENT_CREDENTIALS</oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-type>
            </oauth2-provider:authorized-grant-types>
            <oauth2-provider:scopes>
                <oauth2-provider:scope>SOMETHING</oauth2-provider:scope>
            </oauth2-provider:scopes>
        </oauth2-provider:client>
    </oauth2-provider:clients>
</oauth2-provider:config>

<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
    host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

<flow name="oauthFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        doc:name="HTTP" path="/api" />
    <oauth2-provider:validate config-ref="OAuth_provider_module"
        doc:name="OAuth provider module" scopes="SOMETHING" />
    <custom-processor
        class="com.mulesoft.module.oauth2.ValidatorResponseBuilder" doc:name="Java" />
</flow>
```

Update:

A blob type would be more suitable for the v column. However for the DB2 driver that results in:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [jcc][1091][10824][4.13.127] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.AccessTokenStoreHolder@4ca9421d is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815 Query: insert into ACCESSTOKENOBJECTSTORE (k,v) values (?,?) Parameters: [934GcogFNLR6U6r9uFYa4ABwyYY7CU-O5UP966_38T-Q0JqssQf_ZZWg-tF73jgMoDTUqoPcXD9HT1bYBMvLyQ, org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.token.AccessTokenStoreHolder@4ca9421d]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.rethrow(QueryRunner.java:540) ~[commons-dbutils-1.2.jar:1.2]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:597) ~[commons-dbutils-1.2.jar:1.2]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:653) ~[commons-dbutils-1.2.jar:1.2]
    at org.mule.transport.jdbc.store.JdbcObjectStore$2.process(JdbcObjectStore.java:205) ~[mule-transport-jdbc-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Configuration seems to be working fine for me.
The only thing I changed to make it work is to change the way of creating the DB table and it's data type.
The following script will help you to create the table with the accurate data type in your h2 db:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ACCESSTOKENOBJECTSTORE (
  id NUMBER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  k VARCHAR(256),
  v OTHER,
  constraint ACCESSTOKENOBJECTSTORE_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```